# Mirror going wrong

Tags: mirror, origin

[image]

I'm new in Blender and I'm stuck here for days. Can someone please explain to me, how does the mirror work so badly when both my origin point and 3d cursor are perfectly aligned to the centre of the axes?

Comment: mirror depends on your transforms
just apply transforms

Comment: Thank you so much @GloriaTheAnimator

Comment: If someone answered your question, consider accepting it by pressing the checkbox on the top left of the answer.